# Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator : Cannot find the Azure Active Directory object 'service_principal_name'

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server, az

I am running the following command

```
$sp = az ad sp show --id $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID --query '{objectId: objectId, displayName: displayName}'
az sql server ad-admin create --resource-group data-eastus2 `
    --server-name data-eastus2-sqlsvr `
    --display-name $sp.name `
    --object-id $sp.id
```

which works perflecty fine without providing any Graph API permissions to service principal. 
Trying to mimick this functionality using Az Powershell module, by running the following

```
Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName 'data-eastus2'  -ServerName 'data-eastus2-sqlsvr' -DisplayName $sp.name -ObjectId $sp.id
```

yields an exception

Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator : Cannot find the Azure Active Directory object
'service_principal_name'. Please make sure that the user or group you are authorizing is registered in the
current subscription's Azure Active directory. To get a list of Azure Active Directory groups use Get-AzADGroup, or
to get a list of Azure Active Directory users use Get-AzADUser.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName 'data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzSqlServer...ryAdministrator], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator

Providing Azure Active Directory Graph - Directory.Read.All and Microsoft Graph - Directory.Read.All 
API Permissions didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure CLI `az sql server ad-admin create` will not call Azure AD Graph to validate the parameters you passed, it just calls the REST API [`Server Azure AD Administrators - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/serverazureadadministrators/createorupdate) to set the admin. Even if you pass wrong `--display-name` and `--object-id`(also need to be `Guid` format), the command will also work fine. You could check the details with `--debug` parameter.

[image]

The Azure powershell `Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator` will call Azure AD Graph [`getObjectsByObjectIds: Get objects from a list of object IDs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getobjectsbyobjectids-get-objects-from-a-list-of-object-ids--) to validate if the object is correct or not. And if the result's type is not an `Azure AD security group`, it will further call [`Get a user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-a-user--). So if the result's type is a service principal, it will also call [`Get a user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-a-user--), then it will cause the issue. You could use fiddler tool to catch the reuqest like below.

[image]

[image]

So if you want to use the `Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator`, you could create a `security group`(not office group) in Azure AD, add the service principal to the group, then add the group to the sql server admin, as mentioned in @alphaz18's reply.

```
$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "<object-id>"
$group = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName "joysec"
Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId $group.Id -MemberObjectId $sp.Id
Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "<groupname>" -ServerName "<servername>" -DisplayName $group.DisplayName -ObjectId $group.Id
```

**Note**: To run the script above, you need to give a 
`Directory.ReadWrite.All` *Application permission* of `Azure Active Directory Graph`(not `Microsoft Graph`) for your AD App, and there is some delay, wait for a while and test.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What an excellently written and insightful answer.  Thank you for taking the time to provide it.  I am encountering a similar issue/message and see that Azure Active Directory Graph is being deprecated in June of this year.  The message further states to use Microsoft Graph instead.  Not sure if that impacts your answer, but thought I would mention it for your review.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely though i can't confirm this as i'm not 100% sure, but I think the set-azsqlserveractivedirectoryadministrator, only filters by azaduser or azadgroup. it probably won't search for service principals. 
as a workaround though, if you want to accomplish this. you could create an azure ad group something called dbas or something. and add the service principal to that group. then add the group to the sql server using that set-azsqlcommand.

so something like this:

```
$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "theserviceprincipalname"
Add-AzADGroupMember -MemberObjectId $($sp.id) -TargetGroupDisplayName "AAD Group Name"

Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName 'data-eastus2'  -ServerName 'data-eastus2-sqlsvr' -DisplayName "AAD Group Name"
```

Hope that works for you, not 100% directly answer what you were asking, but I believe it is a viable workaround per your requirements hopefully.